# Get CSS url path from class name

Tags: jquery, css, variables, less, var

I need to use very much images (>600) in a current web(app) project. The way I want to manage them, since I've got almost none PHP/SQL experience, is in css/less.css.

I made a stylesheet called "faces.less" to manage these. My current sheet is like this:

```
.f01 {
background-image: url("{base-url}/f01.png");
}
```

Width, height, etc are managed in another class. But to to this 600+ times feels stupid, isn't there any (simple) way in LESS or jQuery to load the image name from the class name? My ideal solution would look a little like this:

```
.f01, .f02, .f03 {
background-image: url("@{base-url}/{class-name}+png");
```

Any solution is welcome!

Comment: If you have a separate name for every image, they should be ids, not classes - like #f01.  I think JSON or XML would be a better system than CSS though, if you want to avoid databases

Comment: This seems like a ton of work for CSS. Why don't you use a serverside language?

Comment: are you trying to load the image name, or construct the image name from the class name?

Comment: The image name equals to the class name, html is like this
<a href="#" class="faces f305"></a>
<a href="#" class="faces f315"></a>

No ID's, I want to use the ID's for modal functions. Can't use a database since it's a school deliverable and lack of SQL knowledge

Comment: 600+ images?  I can hardly believe *that* many images are non-content images.  Sounds like they should be actual images, not backgrounds.

Comment: @cimmanon The images are actually player's faces. These face need to appear. On different places whitin the website, since I don't want to type 600 img src's, CSS seems a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using LESS 1.3.1+

It was a little challenging to get the leading `0` on the numbers less than `10` to work right with the recursive loop, but this managed it:

**LESS**

```
@base-url: "/blah/blah";
@max-faces: 600; //enter the maximum number of faces to generate code for

.buildFaces(@index, @pre: ~"f0") when (@index =< @max-faces) {
  //build classes
  .@{pre}@{index} {
  background-image: url("@{base-url}/@{pre}@{index}.png");
  }
  //loop 
  .buildFaces((@index + 1), ~`(@{index} + 1) < 10 ? "f0" : "f"`);
}
// end loop
.buildFaces(@index, @pre) when (@index > @max-faces) {}

// start loop
.buildFaces(1);
```

**CSS Output (cut short)**

```
.f01 {
  background-image: url("/blah/blah/f01.png");
}
.f02 {
  background-image: url("/blah/blah/f02.png");
}

...

.f599 {
  background-image: url("/blah/blah/f599.png");
}
.f600 {
  background-image: url("/blah/blah/f600.png");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To construct the image name from the class name, using image tags (I'm not sure the best way with a background-image):

```
var basePath = 'mysite/images/';
$('a').each(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    className = className.replace(/[^f][^0-9]*/, '').replace(' ', '');
    $(this).css('background-image', basePath + className + '.png');
});
```

Comment: I don't want them as src's, I need to use them more then once + CSS background-image loading speeds are faster then HTML

Comment: edited it to what I think should work with anchor tags - give it a try let me know if it works - faces is the only class on all of them right?

Comment: switched to a regular expression and a whitespace remover - regex might need some tweaking, but that's the general idea

Comment: Thanks! But here comes the nooby question: I put it in a .js file with a $(document).ready(function() line above it, but I don't see anything happen (also changed the path). Is the classname still correct? Since it doesn't display .faces (only class on all of them) anymore...

Comment: hmmm... the code above doesn't alter any class names, just retreives them - if you had other JS code that set classes, this might have interfered with that.  But if it was just CSS it shouldn't have an effect.

Comment: adjusted the code to $('a.faces'), no result.
The problem is, it needs to "read" the other class name (variable), since that's the same as the image name

Comment: It's all in the regex expression, if you want to test it without regex try this: className = className.replace('faces', '').replace(' ', '');